# Audio files sound much better played in Audacity than in GNOME Player?

Tags: sound

I use my computer for listening to music. I use high quality flac files and very high quality headphones.

When I listen to a file using Audacity, it is substantially better sounding than listening to exact same file using the Gnome player

Everything is the same in terms of file and equipment. Is this something that can be improved upon in the Lubuntu operating system?

Comment: Have you updated all the software packages on your computer to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Your computer may be the weak link in the chain if that is why you are using Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu. Getting a modern desktop computer would work better than a "duct tape" solution intended to accommodate the limitations of an old computer, however since you asked about something that can be improved upon in Lubuntu, try changing the engine required for playing .flac files in GNOME Media Player (*gnome-media-player*). Changing the engine makes a difference in the quality of the sound that I can hear on multiple computers, and you can't argue with what the ear hears.

There are three different engines in GNOME Media Player. To change the engine, open GNOME Media Player, select *Engine* and select one of these three engines:

- VLC Engine
- Xine Engine
- GStreamer Engine

Then select *Engine* -> *Restart Engine*.

In order to use the VLC Engine you must also install VLC media player (*vlc*).